Why does R's 'ggsave' suppress 'message' behaviour?
I'm running an R script with several loops using RStudio on Posit Workbench. Some of the progress of the loops is tracked by e.g. message("Processing: ", current_iteration).
Annoyingly, when using message in combination with ggsave in a loop, the message statement get's suppressed for future loop iterations.
Some example code:
# Loop
for (i in 1:5) {
  # Message statement
  message("Processing: i = ", i) # This works only the first time
  cat("test ", i, "\n") # This works for every iteration
  
  # Random plot
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
  
  # Save to file
  ggsave(filename = "randomplot.png", plot = p)
}

Also ggsave only prints Saving 7 x 7 in image once to the console. Based on this, I assume that ggsave somehow suppresses any future messages.
Can anyone explain why that is the case and how to deactivate this behaviour?
I know I can also use paste() or cat(), but I'm still curious to understand why this happens.
Other things I've tried are using suppressMessages(ggsave()), but the message() is still suppressed. Also, using flushconsole() doesn't solve the problem.

I cannot reproduce what you describe. I see five messages, five cat outputs and five "Saving 7 x 7 in image"  messages.

Ok that's interesting. I'm using RStudion on a Posit Workbench, maybe that's the issue! I'll add that to the question. I can reproduce it every time, also after a new start-up. The local RStudio works though ...
